# Injective maps $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be an injection for $n>m$. Can $f$ be continuous? Why?

I got this question in mind when I was trying to find a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $f$ is injective and continuous from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$
where $n>m$ then $f$ restricts to a continuous bijection from $S^{n-1}$,
the unit sphere in $R^n$, to a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Thus you can embed $S^{n-1}$, and a foriori $S^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

But there are homological obstructions to embedding $S^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Using the arguments of this excellent paper

Albrecht Dold,
A simple proof of the Jordan-Alexander complement theorem,
*Amer. Math. Monthly* **100** (1993), 856-85.

(essentially a cunning use of the Mayer-Vietoris theorem)
it would entail the homology of the space $\mathbb{R}^m-K$ being nonzero
in negative dimension, which is absurd.

**Added** As I replied in haste I forgot the sledgehammer
that cracks this little nut, namely [Alexander duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality).

**Added later** In fact this result also follows from Brouwer's
Invariance of Domain. 
This is Theorem 2B.3 on page 172 of [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).
This implies that if one has an embedding from
$\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, then its image is open. One gets such an
embedding by composing your putative embedding with the natural embedding of
$\mathbb{R}^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Adapting the proof, gives a swift proof
that the answer of your original question is no.

If you have a continuous injection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$,
with $n>m$ then you have an embedding of $S^{n-1}$ into a nontrivial
hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem
the image $K$ of this embedding separates $\mathbb{R}^n$ but it's easy to
see that since the image is in a hyperplane any two points of
the complement of $K$ can be connected by a path (exercise for reader :-)).

Comment: Hi--
 
  Your proof is very much abstruse. Are there no simpler proofs. 

Comment: There's a simpler argument when m=1. Any such map would induce a continuous map $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{p\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose image is disconnected, a contradiction. Here $p$ is the preimage of any interior point of the original image.

Comment: Chandru: I'm sure you can carry out a more direct homological argument but I'd be surprised if there was a truly elementary proof.

Comment: Chandru, the methods of singular (co)homology theory were
developed to tackle questions like this systematically.
Compare the rather similar Brouwer's Invariance of Domain
theorem.

Comment: Dear all, Chandru usually wishes elementary (or at least "ingenious") arguments; cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34055/transcendence-of-pi .

Comment: I'm no topologist, but it would be interesting for me to know if the answer is "no" if we require $f$ to be continuous except at finitely many points. If not, how about countably many points? or outside a set of measure zero?

Comment: For countably many points of discontinuity, the answer is the same,
as there will be a sphere centred at the origin where the function
is continuous, and that's all you need.

Comment: Set of measure zero, the answer is different.  The Baire space $J$ of irrationals is homeomorphic to $J \times J$, which gives us a 1-1 map from $J \times J$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Chandru, is it a simple question to prove that
$\mathbf{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic for
$m\ne n$?

Comment: I dont know sir! thats why i posted here.

Comment: Chandru, I don't know any way of proving that $\mathbb{R}^m$
and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m\ne n$ save by using the methods
or results of algebraic topology such as homology theory
or the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem. Your question looks
just as hard, and to me at least, it looks unlikely there's
a naive proof.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you may use the [Borsuk-Ulam antipodal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk-Ulam_theorem), in order to prove that such a map cannot be one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, you might ask whether there is a continuous injective map from a space of dimension $n$ to a space of dimension $m$, where $n > m$.  The subject of dimension theory investigates this problem.  (Hurewicz & Wallman wrote a classic, though hard to find nowadays, book on the subject; perhaps an expert could recommend a more modern reference?)  Here is a representative theorem:

If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous surjection bewteen separable compact metric spaces, where $X$ has dimension $n$ and $Y$ has dimension $m$, then there is a point $y \in Y$ whose preimage contains at least $n - m + 1$ points.

This applies to your question, as Robin Chapman explained, by restricting your map to a nice compact subspace of dimension $n$, for instance the unit closed ball.

In any case, my point is that the techniques above for Euclidean space and for spheres have appropriate generalizations to separable metric spaces.

As to the "why?", I recommend tracking down a copy of Hurewicz & Wallman from a library.  It's very pleasant reading and assumes only a brief encounter with point set topology.

Comment: For a more modern reference: Engelking, Theory of Dimensions, finite and infinite. For separable metric spaces, also Jan van Mill, "infinite-dimensional topology, prerequisites and an introduction", or the newer "the infinite-dimensional topology of function spaces", both of which have a chapter on this subject.
 

Answer (score 2):

I taught an introductory topology course this last autumn where I covered this theorem from an elementary point of view. The argument just uses the Brouwer fixed point theorem (which itself has a proof via Stokes' theorem which is readily accessible to students with several variable calculus) plus elementary point set topology. In particular no homology or Jordan--Brouwer separation theorems are used. The treatment was based upon that of Hurewicz & Wallman but was also inspired by Larry Guth's ICM-2010 presentation in Hyderabad.

If you're interested the notes are available on

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/uploads/assets/32_section6.pdf